# Replace non alphanumeric characters and multiple spaces with just 1 space

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to replace all "non alphanumeric characters" and "multiple spaces" with just 1 single space

I have 2 working solutions, however i'm wondering if its possible to combine them efficiently?

Given

```
var str = "ASD S-DF 2134 4@# 4    234234 #$)(u SD";
var options = RegexOptions.None;
```

Solution for **non alphanumeric characters**

```
var rgxAlpha = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
str = rgxAlpha.Replace(str, " ", options);
```

Solution for **multiple spaces**

```
var regexSpace = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}", options);
str = regexSpace.Replace(str, " ");
```

Expected Result

```
ASD S DF 2134 4 4 234234 u SD
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just the below would be enough, since `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` matches also the spaces, you don't need to add `[ ]{2,}` explicitly.

```
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bQ2zU3/1)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming they both work:

```
var rgxPattern = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+|[ ]{2,}");
```

Just add a | between them.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string szOut= "";
    char previous;
    foreach (char cr in str.ToCharArray())
    {
            if(cr == ' '&& previous == ' ')
                continue;

            if (IsAlphaNumeric(cr))
                szOut+= cr;

            previous = cr;
    }       
    return szOut;
```

....

```
    public static Boolean IsAlphaNumeric(char cr)
    {
        return char.IsLetter(cr) || char.IsNumber(cr) || cr == ' ';
    }
```

Comment: This is a rough code pattern I would use. To get the best performance use the char[] directly and add characters as needed and then do String(array)

Comment: You don't need to call ToCharArray().